# Handle DeleteEvent in Event sourcing

Tags: event-sourcing

I have an object of an aggregate root that need to delete it and there is no reference id of it in another aggregates and I aware of that events never deleted , now :

should I delete this object with another event?
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "delete" an aggregate in a event sourced system, as its events are still in the database.

so, instead you should probably have a "Deactivate", "Cancel" or "Disable" command instead to represent a "delete".

see this post: [Don’t Delete – Just Don’t](https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)